# How can I change the email form (mailchimp) on this Delayed Modal Popup to this (getresponse) code?

Tags: javascript, forms, popup, lightbox, modalpopup

This has been a nightmare for me. I can not figure out how to simply change the form code that pops up after 5 seconds. When I do change it, the colors, the fonts everything changes on me. I've tried changing 1 thing at time and at one point I got close but I couldn't change the color of the button and in the explore browser the format was all out of wack... If any one can help me, that would be amazing!

original code

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
(function ()
{
 //Fade in delay for the background overlay (control timing here)
 $("#bkgOverlay").delay(4800).fadeIn(400);
  //Fade in delay for the popup (control timing here)
 $("#delayedPopup").delay(5000).fadeIn(400);
 
 //Hide dialouge and background when the user clicks the close button
 $("#btnClose").click(function (e)
 {
  HideDialog();
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
//Controls how the modal popup is closed with the close button
function HideDialog()
{
 $("#bkgOverlay").fadeOut(400);
 $("#delayedPopup").fadeOut(300);
}
```

```css
.instructions {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  margin: 15vh;
}  

/* //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //   Default Modal Styles   //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
/*   This is the background overlay   */
.backgroundOverlay {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #000000;
 opacity: .85;
 filter: alpha(opacity=85);
 -moz-opacity: .85;
 z-index: 101;
 display: none;
}
/*   This is the Popup Window   */
.delayedPopupWindow {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 width: auto;
 max-width: 480px;
 height: 310px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -260px;
 margin-top: -180px;
 background-color: #efefef;
 border: 2px solid #333;
 z-index: 102;
 padding: 10px 20px;
}
/*   This is the closing button  */
#btnClose {
 width:100%;
 display: block;
 text-align: right;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #BCBCBC;
}
/*   This is the closing button hover state  */
#btnClose:hover {
 color: #c90c12;
}
/*   This is the description headline and paragraph for the form   */
#delayedPopup > div.formDescription {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 44%;
 padding: 1% 3%;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #666;
 clear: left;
}
/*   This is the styling for the form's headline   */
#delayedPopup > div.formDescription h2 {
 color: #444444;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

/* 
////////// MailChimp Signup Form //////////////////////////////
*/

/*   This is the signup form body  */
#delayedPopup #mc_embed_signup {
 float: left;
 width: 47%;
 padding: 1%;
 display: block;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #666;
 margin-left: 1%;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form inputs  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input {
 width: 95%;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form inputs when they are being hovered with the mouse  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input:hover {
 border:solid 2px #40c348;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #AAAAAA;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form inputs when they are focused  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input:focus {
 border:solid 2px #40c348;
 box-shadow: none;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form submit button  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe {
 width: 100%!important;
 height: 40px!important;
 margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
 background: #5D9E62;
 border: none;
 color: #fff;
}
/*   This is the styling for the signup form submit button hover state  */
#delayedPopup #mc-embedded-subscribe:hover {
 background: #40c348;
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow:none!important;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="instructions">Wait for 5 seconds</div>

<div id="bkgOverlay" class="backgroundOverlay"></div>
  
<div id="delayedPopup" class="delayedPopupWindow">
  <!-- This is the close button -->
  <a href="#" id="btnClose" title="Click here to close this deal box.">[ X ]</a>
  <!-- This is the left side of the popup for the description -->
  <div class="formDescription">
    <h2>Sign Up and <span style="color: #40c348; font-weight: bold;">Save $25!</span></h2>
    <p>Sign up for our Deal Alerts and save
      $25 Off of your first order of $50 or more!</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
  <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate="">
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name
          <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name
          <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address
          <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
      </div>

      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
        <input type="text" name="b_2aabb98e55b83ba9d3bd551f5_e6c08b53b4" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="clear">
        <input type="submit" value="Save Money!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- End MailChimp Signup Form -->
</div>
```

THIS IS THE CODE I WOULD LIKE TO CHANGE THE FORM TO -

```
<button type="button" button-data-id="1" id="lead_button_form" div class="form_box" >
```

#### Enter A Valid Name and Email

```
<form class="form-horizontal validate formdetails show" name="optin" id="optin" form action="" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
    <!-- Name -->
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br/>
    <!-- Email field (required) -->
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /><br/>
    <!-- Campaign token -->
    <!-- Get the token at: https://app.getresponse.com/campaign_list.html -->
    <input type="hidden" name="campaign_token" value="G" />
    <!-- Thank you page (optional) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="https://reviewtheinside.com/Easy-eCash-Review-and-Bonuses.htm"/>
    <!-- Add subscriber to the follow-up sequence with a specified day (optional) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="start_day" value="0" />
    <!-- Forward form data to your page (optional) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="forward_data" value="" />
    <!-- Subscriber button -->
    <input type="submit" button type="button" button-data-id="1" id="lead_button" value="SUBMIT"/>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="mbr-row">
                                          <div class="inner-addon right-addon"><p id="smtp-error"></p></div>
                                        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are calling the function properly

```
(function ()
{
    //Fade in delay for the background overlay (control timing here)
    $("#bkgOverlay").delay(4800).fadeIn(400);
  //Fade in delay for the popup (control timing here)
    $("#delayedPopup").delay(5000).fadeIn(400);

    //Hide dialouge and background when the user clicks the close button
    $("#btnClose").click(function (e)
    {
        HideDialog();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})(); //call the function
//Controls how the modal popup is closed with the close button
function HideDialog()
{
    $("#bkgOverlay").fadeOut(400);
    $("#delayedPopup").fadeOut(300);
}
```

Comment: Everything is working fine, I just dont know how to change the sign up form